# How do you set the alt attribute with the Media module widget?

Tags: media

I've tried both 7.x-1/7.x-2 branches of the Media module and can't find a way to set the alt-attribute on a image field using the media-widget.

When I change to the image widget it's possible to set title/alt.

Answer (score 2):

After one whole day of searching and patching without success I finally found out I only simply had to download and enable [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module to make Media correctly set images `alt` and `title` attributes when inserting images in CKEditor wysiwyg. I wonder since this is nowhere stated as an requirement. That's the bundle of modules it finally worked with:

- [media-7.x-2.0-alpha3](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/media-7.x-2.0-alpha3.tar.gz)
- [wysiwyg-7.x-2.2+46-dev](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/wysiwyg-7.x-2.x-dev.tar.gz) + CKEditor profile (CKEditor 4.4.2.1567b48)
- [token-7.x-1.5](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/token-7.x-1.5.tar.gz)

Now I even can use the default view mode to display the `alt` or `title` attribute below the image to use it as an image caption.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases using the media file selector widget:  in conjunction with *fieldS* and in conjunction with WYSIWYG editor image insert pop-up.

There are patches to the Media module for each of these that add alt/title text fields in appropriate places.

See http://drupal.org/node/1307054 and http://drupal.org/node/1343022 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Alt tags and title tags are now available in the 2.x-dev releases of the media module.